# Duplicate app names in battery optimization list

Tags: applications, phone-app, optimization

While troubleshooting a problem with the stock Android Phone app, I was thinking to let the phone app bypass battery optimization and see if that made any difference.  I notice that in the battery optimization list there are two listings for "Phone" with similar blue handset icons in the battery optimization list (as well as one with a green robot icon, and a "Phone Services" and "Phone and Messaging Storage" and "Call Management" all with similar blue handset icons).

Why do I have the apparent duplicate Phone app (with similar, not identical, icons) and how do I find out what the other, phone-related apps do?

I have UNrooted Android 7.0 Nougat on a Motorola Droid Turbo 2.

FWIW, I also see duplicate entries (including identical icons) for "Motorola Settings", "Photos" (with Google Photos icon), and "Setup Wizard".

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Comment: If the reboot while ringing happens every time connect the phone to a charger and make it ring. If it does not reboot with a charger connected it is not a software problem but a hardware (battery).

Comment: It doesn't reboot while ringing.  After I notice that it doesn't ring when called, if I reboot the phone, AND if I hear the normal music when the phone reboots, then it once again rings when called.  Sometimes when I reboot, it reboots silently, and in that case, the phone won't ring either.

I can try plugging the phone in as soon as I notice it's not ringing and test it, but I have noticed that once it stops ringing, the only way to get it to ring again is reboot (as many times as it takes to get a normal reboot with sound).

Rebeccah

Comment: Anyway, I have a different question posted about the ringing failure.  This one is about the duplicate app entries in the Battery Optimization list.  I will update the post to be more clear.